# How to type the intersection of two parameters to be assignable to third

Tags: typescript, static-typing

I'm trying to express an existing API in TypeScript, and it has a function that combines two parameters into the same shape as a third parameter. My attempt to type it so far looks like this (simplified):

```js
type Difference<A, B> = Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>>
export const foo = <Props, A extends Difference<Props, B>, B extends Difference<Props, A>>(
  props: Props,
  a: A,
  b: B,
): Props => ({ ...a, ...b }); // Type 'A & B' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
```

`Props` is the desired shape that `A` and `B` should combine into. My idea was to narrow `A` to extend from its difference with `B` and vice versa, but it produces the error seen in the comment, although it otherwise seems to behave as expected:

```js
const props = { x: 1, y: 1 };
foo(props, { x: 1, z: 1 }, { y: 1 }); // Valid
foo(props, { x: 1 }, {}); // Error
foo(props, { x: 1, y: 1 }, {}); // Valid
```

Should I just add an `as unknown as Props` assertion to the return value?

Comment: If you're reasonably confident that the implementation of `foo()` is type safe, then sure, an assertion is a good solution since it only affects the implementer (you) and not the callers (who could be anyone).

Comment: That's the crux of the question, though—is it type safe? :)

Comment: I *think* so?  Assuming `Props`, `A`, and `B` are plain object types without index signatures, it seems that any key of `Props` must a key of either `A` or `B`, so the intersection `A & B` must contain all keys of `Props`, and since the property values of `A` and `B` must be subtypes of the same-named property values from `Props`, then `A & B` should be a subtype of `Props` itself.  I'm not surprised that the compiler can't figure this out.

Comment: If would probably just make the compiler shut up by casting the result to `any` if the type signature of the function works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach, which may be a bit confusing to the user of the function because the error is on the `props` input. But it makes sure the function cannot be called if the intersection does not work.

`A & B` as return type should always be a subclass of `Props` so that should not be an issue (and causes the compiler to not complain).

```
export const foo2 = <Props, A, B>(
  props: A & B extends Props ? Props : never,
  a: A,
  b: B,
): A & B => ({ ...a, ...b });

const props = { x: 1, y: 1 };
foo2(props, { x: 1, z: 1 }, { y: 1 }); // Valid
foo2(props, { x: 1 }, {}); // Error
foo2(props, { x: 1, y: 1 }, {}); // Valid
foo2(props, {}, { x: 1, y: 1 }); // Valid
```